# Android permissions, python, kivy

Tags: python, android, permissions, kivy

How can I get permissions to write and read files on android device? In this app I try to create folder, the file and write to the file a line.
The app is just dont start. It asks permission to write in the storage when i launch it in the first time.

In logcat i get:

`02-22 10:23:22.339 29320 29348 I python  :  PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/storage/emulated/0/folder'`

My code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.utils import platform
from pathlib import Path

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        text = "1"+App.get_running_app().user_data_dir + '\n'
        self.label = Label(text=text)
        if platform == "android":
            from android.storage import app_storage_path,primary_external_storage_path
            from android.permissions import request_permissions, check_permission, Permission
            self.label.text += primary_external_storage_path() +'\n'
            folder_path = Path(primary_external_storage_path(),"folder")
            request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
            folder_path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
            file = Path(folder_path,"file.txt")
        else:
            file = Path(Path.home(),"file.txt")
        with open(file,"w") as tfile:
            tfile.write("test test")
        return self.label

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

in buildozer.spec i add:

```
# (list) Permissions
# (See https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/buildoptions/#build-options-1 for all the supported syntaxes and properties)
android.permissions = android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.permission.INTERNET
```

Answer (score 1):

use android.permissions to remove PermissionError

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
    request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: I tried it and i get 02-26 09:31:37.717 32748   339 I python  :  PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/storage/emulated/0/folder' all the same